# "How about you start tomorrow?"

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-usage, colloquial-language

Does this a common phrase? Or at least does it sound natural?

I know this is quite common:

> "Okay, you have the job. **How about starting tomorrow**?"

But I'm not sure about this:

> "Okay, you have the job. **How about you start tomorrow**?"

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the intended nuance might be here. ***How about XXX?*** is an idiomatic usage that normally implies ***one*** of two possible meanings (1: ***I** want **and expect** you to do XXX*, 2: *Do **you** want to do XXX?*). The guy who just got the job might have very good reasons for not wanting to start until next week, but be afraid to ask if he can start later because he thinks his new boss is *ordering* him to start tomorrow. Maybe the new boss doesn't care that he's putting the guy in an awkward position, but I'd rather be asked ***Would you be able to** start tomorrow?*

Comment: Compare ***How about** you keep your nose out of my business?* and ***How about** we go out to eat tonight?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your phrases are idiomatic and correct English, however, they are in a very [casual register](https://drsaraheaton.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/language-register-and-why-it-matters-or-why-you-cant-write-an-academic-paper-in-gangsta-slang/).  In some parts of America (such as California), and for certain job types (such as "[Blue Collar](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue-collar_worker)" jobs), a casual register *might* be used even in formal situations such as hiring a new employee.

However, many people would consider hiring a new employee to be a situation that requires a formal register, and neither of the phrases in your question would be appropriate.  "How about" is simply quite casual.